# How to get rid of two app icons in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I recently took over a Xamarin project that displays two Android icons every time I load the project. The problem only occurs in the Android project not in iOS. If I uninstall one of the app icons, both of them gets removed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all your Activity in your Xamarin.Android project and make sure you only have one MainLauncher set to `true`.